# Get first row of all pages while also paginating (LIMIT / OFFSET)

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination

I have a table of entries (basically: words) that can be sorted alphabetically. I know the total number of pages already so I can display something like
`1 2 3 ... 19 20` with an OnClick handler to flip to new pages. If the result for a specific page has already been loaded, it will simply show it, otherwise a new SQL request is issued with OFFSET and LIMIT.

Now it would be great to have a tooltip showing the first entry on each page, when a user hovers over the link for page "3". I know I could issue a request onMouseOver, but is it possible to get this list in the very first query already?

Example table *words*:

```
+-ID-+----Word---+
+  1 + ability   +
+  2 + able      +
+  3 + about     +
+  4 + above     +
+  5 + accept    +
+  6 + according +
+  7 + account   +
+----+-----------+
```

Example initial query (obviously *LIMIT 2* would be something like *LIMIT 50* in real query)

`SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY word ASC LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0`

Example further query (e.g. if user clicked on page "3"):

`SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY word ASC LIMIT 2 OFFSET 4`

Desired result:

I'd love to have **one** initial query that returns *ability* and *able* (obviously) but then also returns *about* (first item on page 2), *accept* (first item on page 3) and *account* (first item on page 4). Again, I'm sure this would be easy with an event handler on MouseOver or something like this or also probably be not too hard with two subsequent queries, but I'd love to do it in one query if possible. It'd be best if the "first-of-other-pages" items would be named differently, but I guess that would be manageable differently as well. The initial query will always be with `OFFSET 0` (i.e. the user can't start on page 12).

Currently on PostgreSQL Version 12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one query that returns the *nth* row, you can use `row_number()` and modulo arithmetic:

```
select w.*
from (select w.*, row_number() over (order by word) as seqnum
      from words w
     ) w
where w.seqnum % 50 = 1;
```

You may be able to do this using just `id`, if it is sequential, gapless, starts with 1, and represents the ordering of the words.

Comment: It's going to be an expensive query, so probably the OP wants to run it only once at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for taking to time to look into this. This would have to be part of a UNION statement, right? Because I do want to have all 50 entries of the first page *plus* every nth-row.  @the-impaler Thanks for pointing out that it might be expansive, will check (Edit: Trying to use "@" correctly...)

Comment: For those interested: I ended up using a UNION statement, with the first part having 'NULL AS seqnum' (so that it's the same number of rows). The costs in my case are: Original query: Planning Time: 17.359 ms / Execution Time: 6.480 ms New query (with UNION clause): Planning Time: 21.506 ms / Execution Time: 10.538 ms (for one example query with not too many entries in total)